# npm dependencies require different versions

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have two packages, which rely on different versions of `sass`.

`vuetify` requires `sass@1.32.1`

`@org/myPackage` requires `sass@1.52.0`
Running my project with either versions causes a problem when running the applications related to the sass version

Now I want to use two different versions. I tried using resolutions without success, because it only allows me to use one version of sass.

```
"dependencies": {
   "vuetify": "2.5.14",
}
"devDependencies": {
    "sass": "1.32.13",
  },
  "overrides": {
    "@org/myPackage": {
      "sass": "^1.42.0"
    },
}
```

What other possibilities are there?